# Issue with return argument msg.sender

Tags: solidity, remix

[image]

Hi guys, I'm stuck in here. Thank you for helping

Comment: which sol version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

From Solidity version [0.6.0](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.6.0):

> Allow explicit conversions from address to address payable via
> payable(...).

So your return statement needs to coerce/cast `msg.sender` to a payable address:

```
return payable(address(msg.sender));
```

Comment: Originally it was pragma 0.6.12 but I've changed it to 0.8.1 according to the recommended compiler.  Is changing it causes the error?